# New Criteria of Isomorphism + Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

The following questions were suggested by my friend, while we were studying fundamental group theory. We had no exact ideas of the way to approach the problems.

**Questions**

> (1) Let $G$ and $H$ be groups such that $|H|=|G|$. If we can make a bijection $\phi:G\to H$ such that for $\forall a\in G$, $ord(a)=ord(\phi(a))$, then does $G\cong H$?

> (2) Let $G$ be a group. If all of the elements in $G$ except $e$ have the same order, then is $G$ an abelian group?

Both suggestions were not easy to find the counter-examples. So, we wanted to prove these statements instead, but again too difficult. We also failed to find these types of questions on the internet. Is there theories or propositions related to the problems? Thanks.

Comment: For $(1)$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019720/if-two-finite-groups-have-the-same-number-of-elements-of-the-same-order-does-th).  For $(2) $ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452344/show-that-every-nontrivial-element-of-the-heisenberg-group-is-of-order-p) , the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb F_p$. So both questions are duplicates.

Comment: Concerning $2$ : For a counterexample see here : https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime-cube_order_group:U(3,3)

Comment: Note that all counterexamples to (2) must be groups of prime power order, by [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: @Stahl unless infinite.

Comment: @freakish Good point! For some reason I had been assuming we were necessarily working with finite groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) Let $G$ and $H$ be groups such that $|H|=|G|$. If we can make a bijection $\phi:G\to H$ such that for $\forall a\in G$, $ord(a)=ord(\phi(a))$, then does $G\cong H$?

Yes, if both are finite abelian. This follows from the classification of finite abelian groups, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/two-finite-abelian-groups-with-the-same-number-of-elements-of-any-order-are-isom).

No, if both are infinite, even abelian. The simple counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

No, if one of them is non-abelian, even when both finite: the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p) over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and the corresponding $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^n$.

For a deeper discussion on the subject read this: [Is a finite group uniquely determined by the orders of its elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729611/is-a-finite-group-uniquely-determined-by-the-orders-of-its-elements)

> (2) Let $G$ be a group. If all of the elements in $G$ except $e$ have the same order, then does $G$ an abelian group?

No. Neither in finite nor in infinite case (with finite order). For finite case we have the already mentioned [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p), for infinite case [the Tarski monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group).

Comment: In $1)$ , $G$ and $H$ need not be abelian groups.

Comment: For a counterexample with finite groups see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296833/if-i-know-the-order-of-every-element-in-a-group-do-i-know-the-group).

Comment: @Peter Ups, for some reason I thought we talk about abelian groups in (1). Fixed.